# Web-farm suitable implementation of SessionSecurityTokenCache

Tags: wif, web-farm

I need to implement [SessionSecurityTokenCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokencache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to be able to use WIF in a load-balanced web farm. Is there a web-farm suitable (e.g. SQL based) implementation of this class that I can use, or do I really need to create my own?

Comment: I am not sure if there's a built-in implementation but you might want to reference the following question, which does offer some sample code of a custom implementation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015542/azure-web-farm-ready-securitytokencache